# Can't use 9.png in XML from mipmap folder

Tags: android, nine-patch

So Android Studio now have this `mipmap` folder where you should have your images with multiple resolutions (mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi).

Using [Simple-Nine-Patch-Generator](http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/nine-patches.html) i get my let's say *photo.9.png*.

I am trying to set background to view, but i can only link to images from `drawable` folder. I have my multiple *photo.9.png* in my mipmap, when trying to type `@mipmap/` autocomplete offers `@mipmap/photo.9`. But there is error (. [dot] is not valid char). When typing `@mipmap/photo` i get again get error (can't resolve symbol '`@mipmap/photo`').

I can only link .9.png from `drawable` folder, but i can't make multiple resolution of same image in `drawable`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28742085/android-studio-mipmap-and-9-patch-drawables

Comment: similar question, but doesn't solve my problem with multiple resoltuion 9-patch drawables

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Mipmap?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28424952/android-mipmap)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to go to ProjectView and make directories in /res (drawable-hdpi and others), then you can add your .9.png in proper directories and link it in your project.